# Cmake : /bigobj: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

When I was building an application of mine which used Assimp, I got an error

```
C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Vs3q.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Vs3q.s: Fatal error: can't write 117 bytes to section .text of CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\AssetLib\IFC\IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.obj because: 'File too big'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\AssetLib\IFC\IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.obj: too many sections (46774)
C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Vs3q.s: Fatal error: can't close CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\AssetLib\IFC\IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.obj: File too big
Nade\vendor\assimp\code\CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\build.make:1965: recipe for target 'Nade/vendor/assimp/code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/AssetLib/IFC/IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.obj' failed
```

So I searched online for solutions and I found a solution that said that I need to set the `/bigobj` flag.

I am using Cmake and Mingw32-make.

But when I add the definition like this

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /bigobj)
```

or like that

```
add_definitions(/bigobj)
```

I Get the error

```
/bigobj: No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this error while solving the Too Big OBJ file error at the same time?

Comment: Options started with forward slash (`/`) are usually used on Windows. In Unux environment (MinGW uses Unix-like environment too) options are usually passed as dash-prefixed (`-`). So `/bigobj` is definitely not suitable as an option for the compiler under MinGW. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact** error message about "Too Big OBJ file".

Answer (score 8):

The `/bigobj` option is for Microsoft Visual Studio compiler.

For GCC, try `-Wa,-mbig-obj` instead.

If you want to support both, try:

```
if (MSVC)
  add_compile_options(/bigobj)
else ()
  add_compile_options(-Wa,-mbig-obj)
endif ()
```

If you want to specify directly only a single target:

```
target_compile_options(my_target_name PRIVATE /bigobj)
```

Comment: there's a typo, add_definition should be add_definitions

Comment: for curiosity: is there a reason to use `add_definitions()` here instead of `add_compile_options()`? According to the [CMake Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) the latter seems to be the better choice (and it also supports generator Expressions)

Comment: No reason that I remember... I'll update the answer.